# How Can I make this website more responsive?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I am trying to make this website responsive, its kinda responsive but not really.
the checkboxes are the biggest problem. I cant make them responsive... they have to stay centered even if I make the page smaller.
Can you guys help me to make this website more responsive?
https://www.ffat20.nl/champions

the code below is only of the checkboxes

```
    <<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class ="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-2"> 
      <input id="box1" class="box" type="checkbox" />
      <label for="box1">Fighter</label>
    </div>
    <div class ="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-2">  
      <input id="box2" class="box" type="checkbox" />
      <label for="box2">Assassin</label>
    </div>
    <div class ="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-2"> 
      <input id="box3" class="box" type="checkbox" />
      <label for="box3">Support</label>
    </div>
    <div class ="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-2"> 
      <input id="box4" class="box"  type="checkbox" />
      <label for="box4">Marksman</label>
    </div>
    <div class ="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-2"> 
      <input id="box5" class="box" type="checkbox" />
      <label for="box5">Tank</label>
    </div>
     <div class ="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-2"> 
      <input id="box6" class="box" type="checkbox" />
      <label for="box6">Tank</label>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.filter{
    margin-left: 30%;
}
/*PIC*/
.pic {

  overflow: hidden;
  border: solid 5px;
  border-color:#8a92b3; 
  margin: 5%;
  float: left;
}

.pic:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}




.box{
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
}

label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 15px 30px 15px 62px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #6a8494;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .2s, box-shadow .2s;
  transition: background-color .2s, box-shadow .2s;
}

label::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 32px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .2s;
  transition: background-color .2s;
}

label:first-of-type {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-40px);
          transform: translateX(-40px);
}

label:last-of-type {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(40px);
          transform: translateX(40px);
}

label:hover, input:focus + label {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}

input:checked + label {
  background-color: #ab576c;
}

input:checked + label::before {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: This is very opinionated. I think you should make each checkbox the same width, it will look more harmonious. Then, add a class to each col and with a media query, make it so it has text-align center when its in the range of "sm" and "xs".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `text-align:center` on the columns like this:

```
.checks [class*=col-]{
  text-align:center;
}
```

and add a class `checks` to the `row` containing it.

```
<div class="row checks">
    <!-- here comes the columns and the checkboxes -->
</div>
```

Altogether:

```css
.filter {
  margin-left: 30%;
}


/*PIC*/

.pic {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: solid 5px;
  border-color: #8a92b3;
  margin: 5%;
  float: left;
}

.pic:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
}

label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 15px 30px 15px 62px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #6a8494;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .2s, box-shadow .2s;
  transition: background-color .2s, box-shadow .2s;
}

label::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 32px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .2s;
  transition: background-color .2s;
}

label:first-of-type {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-40px);
  transform: translateX(-40px);
}

label:last-of-type {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(40px);
  transform: translateX(40px);
}

label:hover,
input:focus+label {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}

input:checked+label {
  background-color: #ab576c;
}

input:checked+label::before {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.checks [class*=col-] {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row checks">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-2">
      <input id="box1" class="box" type="checkbox">
      <label for="box1">Fighter</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-2">
      <input id="box2" class="box" type="checkbox">
      <label for="box2">Assassin</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-2">
      <input id="box3" class="box" type="checkbox">
      <label for="box3">Support</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-2">
      <input id="box4" class="box" type="checkbox">
      <label for="box4">Marksman</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-2">
      <input id="box5" class="box" type="checkbox">
      <label for="box5">Tank</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-2">
      <input id="box6" class="box" type="checkbox">
      <label for="box6">Tank</label>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```